# Numpy slice variable length matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix a with shape k x 3. And based on the first index I want to slice it and store. The first index has values 1:1000. While I am done slicing, I don't know how to store it as the length of slices is variable. For example, Y shapes are (163, 2), (55,2) and so on. How do I store this data so that I can recall based on indices such as X[0], X[1], ..., X[999]?

```py
def parseX(a, len):
  X = []
  for i in range(len):
    #Z = np.split(a, np.where(a[:, 0] == i+1))
    ### Split based on 0th column's value being (i+1)
    Y = a[ a[:,0] == i+1, :][:, [1,2]]
    print(Y.shape)
    #X[i] = Y
    #X[i].append(Y)
  #print(len(X))
  return X
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply X.insert(i,Y) works.

```py
def parseX(a, len):
  X = []
  for i in range(len):
    ### Split based on 0th column's value being (i+1)
    Y = a[ a[:,0] == i+1, :][:, [1,2]]
    print(Y.shape)
    X.insert(i, Y)
  #print(len(X))
  return X
```